# UIWebView only loads link after the second try

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I've searched this issue for a solid amount of time, and I couldn't find an answer that solved my problem. If there are any similar questions that I missed and that have a working solution, please post a link to them.

Anyways...

I have a menu filled with buttons that, when clicked, opens up a UIWebView which opens a specific webpage. Everything works fine, but only after the second try. To be a little more clear, the first time I tap a button, the webpage gets stuck loading, but after you close it out and tap it again, the pages load up just fine.

Since I'm using multiple buttons, I decided to put them all in an IBOutlet Collection:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *btnArray;
```

I then set up an array that would hold all the buttons from the collection, set up a view controller for our webview class (we have a separate class for webviews, which has not caused me any problems in the past) and the webview's navigation controller, and finally I used a for loop to add all the buttons the array.

```
NSMutableArray *theButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

webVC = [[WebviewViewController alloc] init];
webNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webVC];

for(int i = 0; i < [btnArray count]; i++)
{
    UIButton *btn = btnArray[i];
    btn.tag = i;
    [theButtons addObject:btn];
    [theButtons[i] addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

I also have set up an array with the end links of all the pages I need to go to, which will be appended to a url:

```
pages = @[@"exOne.php", @"exTwo.php", @"exThree.php", @"exFour.php", @"exFive.php", @"exSix.php"];
```

Note: all the above code in -viewDidLoad

Here is the method that handles what happens when a button is clicked:

```
-(void)buttonPressed : (id) sender
{
    UIButton *clicked = (UIButton *) sender;

    NSMutableString *url = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"http://www.example.org/examples/"];


    for(int i = 0; i < [btnArray count]; i++)
    {
        if(i == clicked.tag)
        {
            [url appendString:pages[i]];
            [webVC loadURL:url];
            webNav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
            webNav.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backPressed)];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:webVC animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

If it wasn't clear from the method call

[webVC loadURL:url];

just sends the link to our webviewViewController class and loads the link.

Any ideas on why the webpages only load after the second attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Your `WebviewViewController` has probably not been loaded when you call loadURL the first time. If the view controller is not loaded it's subviews and hence it's embedded `UIWebView` are not available. When you push  the controller it gets loaded and the second time loadURL will work.